# How to show application name in taskmanager when hosted in IIS

Tags: .net, iis, coreclr

We have 3 .net core applications running in production. All the applications are hosted in IIS.  When i verify TaskManager I have noticed memory spiked in one of the application. I wanted to find out which application is causing it. The taskmanager only shows process name as `dotnet`

[image]

Is there anyway to show actual application name in taskmanager?

Comment: Mission impossible.

Answer (score 5):

In the **Task Manager** goto '**Details**' tab add the '**command line**' column to be displayed.  This will show the ***dll*** (and the path) that is being hosted in the dotnet host process.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In the details tab, the username column should show the app pool name, assuming you have setup an app pool as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x